# CameraRoll addBitmapData() to folder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I know that with AIR AS3 `CameraRoll addBitmapData()` I am able to store a taken image to the dedicated media library of a device.

Now the question: Is there a way to create a separate browseable folder for my app to add the images to with that method? Or is there any other way to keep the images I want to store separated from other images?

EDIT: So this is how i accomplished it in the end:

```
var imageFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("DCIM/yourfolder/");
if(!imageFile.exists) imageFile.createDirectory();
imageFile = imageFile.resolvePath("yourfile.jpg");

var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(imageFile, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(byteArray);
fileStream.close();
```

Comment: i added my code as well below... essentially the same thing...just saw your edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR will allow you to access to your local filesystem. You can use the flash native `File` class which has a range of air specific arguments to allow saving and moving files without a dialog and has far less security restrictions. The standard `save` function will work without air but insists a dialog box.

Official documentation here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Ive implemented this in an old photo booth app I wrote... I will try to dig it up and post what I have.

EDIT:

Firstly, the libraries were as follows:

```
adobe.air.filesystem.*;
adobe.air.filesystem.events.*;
```

This is what the AIR implement looks like:

```
function saveMyFile(){

var imgFile:String 
// however you define your filename;
var f:File=File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("myfolder/" + imgFile); 
//defines the directory, attaches the filename
var s:FileStream=new FileStream();
//creates the filestream

s.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
s.writeBytes(jpgStream); 
// in this case jpgStream was bitmapData var compiled from a screenshot
s.close();
}
```

I just had to navigate to a folder on my desktop, but I'm sure there are more thorough ways to dig in.